# React Native: Scene/Component not being rendered when returned fromm renderScene

Tags: navigation, react-native, render

Been at this for hours.. 
I have a simple Navigation setup and I'm simply trying to display my default scene.

My main Component/App is "myRN" w/c simply has a Navigation component.

I have a default scene is in a "MyScene" class setup for my default scene (home page)..

Funny thing is, if i simply render>return this MyScene class from my main , the scene is displayed fine.

But if being rendered through the renderScene routine, MyScene is not rendered, and view is just blank, no errors.

See @ RNPLAY.org
https://rnplay.org/apps/w5-GSQ

As you can see i have an alert being called during the switch statement, making sure the statement is being called properly.

```
renderScene(route,navigator){


switch(route.id){
  case 'A':
    alert('routing to A');

      return(<MyScene title="My Scene A!" />);
      break;
  case 'B':
    alert('routing to B ');
      return(<MyScene title="My Scene B!"  />);
      break;

  default:
      return (<Text>Aha!</Text>);


}
```

TESTS: 
1) If I remove the navigation block and simply render the part 
      return();
the Scene is rendered just fine, proving that the statement is valid.

2) the case A is definitely being triggered because i get the alert().. but somehow the Scene is just not being rendered

stomped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove curly braces around `this.renderScenene(route, navigator)`.

Here is a working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/Skxjuw

Comment: ok that worked... but why the heck did the curlies cause the issue? isn't the ARROW FUNC supposed to have curlies? surely the format is ()={}  .. why did this become a problem all of a sudden?